# Incompatible character encodings error

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to run a ruby script which generates translated HTML files from a JSON file. However I get this error:

```
incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and CP850
```

Ruby

```
translation_hash = JSON.parse(File.read('translation_master.json').force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("utf-8", replace: nil))
```

It seems to get stuck on this line of the JSON:

Json

```
"3": "Klassisch geschnittene Anzüge",
```

because there is a special character `"ü"`. The JSON file's encoding is ANSI. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Check out this article- http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/05/ruby-1-9-encodings-a-primer-and-the-solution-for-rails/

Comment: HI, dI don't have much idea about ruby, I'm a front end dev and was given the script, what exactly do I have to do?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `# encoding: UTF-8` to the top of the ruby file. This tells ruby to interpret the file with a different encoding. If this doesn't work try to find out what kind of encoding the text uses and change the line accordingly.

Comment: hi, you mean the JSON file when you say text?

Comment: the encoding of the JSON file is ANSI

Answer (score 1):

IMHO **your code should work** if the encoding of the json file is "ISO-8859-1" and if it is a valid json file.

So you should first verify if "ISO-8859-1" is the correct encoding and 
by the way if the file is a valid json file.

```
# read the file with the encoding, you assume it is correct
json_or_not = File.read('translation_master.json').force_encoding("ISO-8859-1")

# print result and ckeck if something is obscure
puts json_or_not
```

Comment: Uups I forgot to ask you for your ruby version. 2.0 is ok 1.9.3 should be ok too, but I'm not sure. With 1.8.7 and older things are different.